# How to create a persistent port forwarding using ssh?

Tags: port-forwarding

I am currently using ssh to forward few ports like this:

There are 3 machines:

- `A-host` - machine building the tunnel, one that can access both `B` and `C`
- `B-host` - machine that does not have access to A or C that that needs to be able to connect to `C:636`
- `C-host` - machine providing a service on port 636

`A-host>ssh -R  636:C-host:636 -R 8080:C-host:8080 root@B-host`

The question is how to make this tunnelling be persistent, to restore it even one or another machine is restarted.

I know that this probably require autossh but that't not the entire solution.

Answer (score 7):

Here is my current solution, if you know a better one, I will be grad to accept it.

On the machine that is initialting the tunnelling:

```
/etc/cron.d/autossh
@reboot autossh -f -nNT -R 3269:host-providing:3269 firewalled-host &
```

Now the firewalled-host can connect to localhost:3269 to access the service that was unavailable before.

Answer (score 4):

Add the `autossh` command to a service that manages system services.

Most Linux setups use init, reading the configuration of what to start from `/etc/inittab`, a line something like `rc:2:respawn:autossh <options> >>/var/log/autosshoutput 2>&1` would do the trick. That will (if you are in runlevel 2 which is the usual case for a running Linux system these days) start the process on boot and restart it if it dies. If you want it to start before the next reboot, run `telinit` to tell the init process to reread its config. See the man page for `inittab` for more details.

Some Linux distributions have moved to using upstart to manage what init used to (amongst upstart's other features, as it does more then init ever did) - you should find plenty of documentation on this easily.

Comment: You might want to also include options like ExitOnForwardFailure to avoid ssh logging in successfully when the forwarding fails.  Be sure to put a reasonable timeout between retries.

Comment: Please provide the <options> for autossh, I tried the same -R ... as the ones used for SSH but it doesn't build the tunnel. I should warn you that 1.2.3.4 IP address is a remote one (3rd machine which is accesible from the machine running auto-ssh but not form.

Comment: The options should be the same as for `ssh`. One thing to account for is that tasks run by `init` will be run as root not your user, so you will need to login via keys and make sure root-on-the-source-machine's key is trusted by the destination end.